# May I have a full list of Windows Azure Diagnostics performance counter name?

Tags: windows, performance, azure, performancecounter, azure-diagnostics

When enabling performance counters in Windows Azure Diagnostics I have to specify the counters using some magic string literals like `\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time`. I can't find a list of possible string literals.

Is there a list anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding my comment as an answer at behest of @sharptooth :)

Once you RDP into your VM, open up command prompt and type "typeperf -q" to list all the available performance counters on your VM. As @Sandrino Di Mattia mentioned, you can save the result in a text file by using "typeperf -q > counters.txt".

Please note that you may get different performance counters depending on the kind of role VM is hosting - Web Role or Worker Role.

Answer (score 3):

This is the Windows Performance monitoring infrastructure.

However you are correct that it is very hard to find something real list over on internet. But here are couple of links that will help you.

- [List of Performance Counters to use with Azure Web Roles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/04/01/list-of-performance-counters-for-windows-azure-web-roles.aspx)
- [Good List of Performance Counters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joelo/archive/2007/01/16/good-list-of-performance-counters.aspx)

Rest is searching the internet with your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Azure server with Remote Desktop Connection. Run perfmon and add a new counter, voila there's your list.

Comment: perfmon doesn't show those weird-looking strings like `\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time`, it shows human-friendly names.

Comment: I believe the command you need to run is "typeperf -q". This will give you the list of all available performance counters on a particular machine.

Comment: Respect for "typeperf -q" command! I used to write all kinds of console apps to export all performance counters, but this is so much easier with "typerperf -q > counters.txt"

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri: That's just great, could you please add that as a separate answer?

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, based on Gaurav Mantri's comment this is the list that I get from my Web role. This is the output of `typeperf -q`. I assume different Azure roles have different counters, and they may even vary between Web roles. Ours is a Medium size.

The list is too big for a post on SO, so here's a github gist:
https://gist.github.com/seibar/74b376aa1c57f2f7c2fd